# Set XSLTProcessor stream context in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xslt, cookies

**How do I tell the PHP `XSLTProcessor()` object to send some HTTP headers (like cookie, user-agent,...) when processing a `document()` command inside the XSL stylesheet?**

---

*Use case*

This is the nearly-void XML (`index.xml`) that the HTTP request calls for

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="process.xsl"?>

<data>
    <coucou/>
</data>
```

It's processed using that XSL (`process.xsl`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="doc" select="document('cookie-en-xml.php')"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="$doc/data/cookie"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which calls this PHP document that outputs an XML through `document('cookie-en-xml.php')`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
    <cookie>
    <?php
        echo( htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['peanuts'], ENT_QUOTES|ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8', true)  );
    ?>
    </cookie>
</data>
```

When processed on client side, no problem: the user agent calls the first almost-void XML (`index.xml`), then executes the `process.xsl` which calls the `cookie-en-xml.php` sending cookies and other HTTP headers.

When build on server side, the client calls `xsl-builder.php`:

```
    $streamContext = stream_context_create($streamContextOptions);
// set stream context with cookies, UA, and so on
// this stream is based on client's cookies and UA,
// so I would like these headers to be send
// when the "document()" calls are processed in the XSL

libxml_set_streams_context($streamContext);
// I though it would also apply for the ``document()`` inside the XSL...
// but apparently, it does not...

$xmlDocument = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDocument->load('cookie-en-xml.php');
// because here, the dynamic XML is finely loaded:
// cookies values appear if I var_dump the $xmlDocument::C14N()
// ...

$xslDocument = new DOMDocument();
$xslDocument->load($xslURI);

$xmlDocument = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDocument->load($xmlURI);

$xslProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
$xslProcessor->importStylesheet($xslDocument);
// ...but here, the document() calls are made by the XSLTProcessor without cookies

$htmlDocument = $xslProcessor->transformToDoc($xmlDocument);
// The http headers received by ``cookie-en-xml.php`` is void,
// so is the output after execution of the XSL
```

*Problem*: the `XSLTProcessor()` calls `cookie-en-xml.php` without sending cookies nor user-agent (because it's the server, not the client that process the XSL).

**How do I tell the `XSLTProcessor()` to send some HTTP headers (cookie, user-agent,...) when processing a `document()` command?**

Thanks